# Why htmlspecialchars_decode in PHP does not have the charset parameter as in its counterpart?

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

There is a charset parameter in htmlspecialchars but the decode version does not have it. In comparison to the similar htmlentities, the encode and decode functions both have the charset parameter. So I can't choose what charset I am decoding back to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars()` requires the charset parameter only when converting charsets who's special characters are not in the 'default' positions. Hence, charsets ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15, UTF-8, cp866, cp1251, cp1252, and KOI8-R do not require the charset parameter.

`htmlspecialchars_decode()` converts entities (`&amp; &quot; &#039; &lt; &gt;`) back to their character equivalent and therefore does not need to be passed a charset.

As `htmlentities()` converts 'all' characters to their equivalent entity, a charset can be passed in `html_entity_decode()` to ensure the entities are decoded to the relevant character in the charset.

Answer (score 6):

Simply because it only converts `&amp; &quot; &#039; &lt; &gt;` and nothing else.

If you want to decode all entities, use [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php), you can pass the charset as the third parameter to it.